# Passing String from TextField To Another Class

Tags: java, mysql

I want to pass the customer name to the class `StartSearchByName2`, I am using `netbeans IDE`. The customer name is got from the `Jtextfield`. 
Please provide me some solution. I have basic knowledge about `Java`, and I am stuck with this for about 6 hours.

Class StartSByName

```
 public class StartSByName extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 String Customername;
  public void close() {
   WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
}


     String NameM(String Name){
     Name = Customername;
     System.out.println(Name);
     return Name;
 }
public StartSByName() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
jButtonAction5(evt);
}                                                                                 
public void jButtonAction5(ActionEvent evt) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/holt", "root", "");
        st=con.prepareStatement("select * from customers where Name=?");
        Customername = jTextField1.getText();
        st.setString(1, Customername);
        rs = st.executeQuery();        
        jTextField1.setText(Customername);
        if (rs.next()) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer Found With ID = " + rs.getString("ID"));
          jTextField1.setText(Customername);
            String Name = null;
           NameM(Name);  // Calling NameM 
           StartSearchByName2 SB = new StartSearchByName2();
            SB.setVisible(true);
            close(); 
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer Does Not Exist");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex);
    }   }
```

Class StartSearchByName2

```
public class StartSearchByName2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String Name;
StartSByName Sb= new StartSByName();
public StartSearchByName2() {
    System.out.println(Sb.NameM(Name));
```

Output

```
Tabish Raza // This Output from StartSByName Class and when calling NameM
null // From StartSearchByName2, its twice null, but i called once and it is not giving me Correct String.
null //
```

Comment: you need to set those value first, you can pass them either in constructor or use setter method.
Be specific about your problem, no body has time to read whole stuff you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class StartSearchByName2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String Name;

    public StartSearchByName2(String pName) {
        Name = pName;
        System.out.println(Name);
}
```

In your first class change the following statement

```
StartSearchByName2 SB = new StartSearchByName2();
```

to

```
StartSearchByName2 SB = new StartSearchByName2(Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was Able to Solve this problem by just using Static String for customer Name. 
Then Later when i call this string in second class, i will get the last updated value of this string.